# Why do the firebase cli give a TypeError

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli, sendgrid-api-v3

I already have some firebase cloud functions that runs fine, and now I try to add SendGrid functionality to one of the functions as described in https://youtu.be/JVy0JpCOuNI. The firebase CLI won't run my code because it says it has a TypeError

The code is written in Typescript and the transpiler doesn't give any error. I am using the latest versions of the CLI and the SDK.

```
admin.initializeApp();

const firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
const SENDGRID_API_KEY = firebaseConfig.sendgrid.key;

const sgMail = require(‘@sendgrid/mail’);
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);
```

I have checked that the firebase config contains the sendgrid key:

```
$ firebase functions:config:get
{
    "sendgrid": {
      "key": "MY_SEND_GRID_KEY"
    }
}
```

I get this output when I try to deploy --only functions:

> functions: Failed to load functions source code. Ensure that you have the latest SDK by running npm i --save firebase-functions inside the functions directory. :warning:  functions: Error from emulator. Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property ‘key’ of undefined

It is this line that has the error:

```
const SENDGRID_API_KEY = firebaseConfig.sendgrid.key;
```

What can I change so I don't get this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables that you set using the CLI via `firebase functions:config:get` don't end up in `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG`.  They end up in `functions.config()`.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
const key = functions.config().sendgrid.key
```

FIREBASE_CONFIG just determines how the admin SDK should be initialized with no parameters passed to admin.initializeApp().

[Please read the documentation for more information.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env)

Comment: I tried this and it works when I deploy my functions. But when I run from the emulator I still get the 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined'. Don't the emulator read the configuration from the server? If not is there a way to set it locally so the emulator can be used?

Comment: Read the documentation on the local emulator. You will have to dump your config to a local file to be read by the emulator. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator